# How to properly clone an entity with some modified fields and persist into database?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Lets say I have an entity like this,

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "post")

public class Post {


@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String title;

@OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "post",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
    orphanRemoval = true,
    FetchType.LAZY
)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<PostComment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToOne(
    mappedBy = "post",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
    orphanRemoval = true, 
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY
)
private PostDetails details;

}
```

I want clone this entity, modified a few fields and then persist the new cloned entity in the database. What's the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: You have references - what do you want to do with those referenced entities? Ie shallow or full cloning? There is no best approach as most require customizations based on the specific business requirements. Some providers (EclipseLink) have copy methods you can use, but it is usually more straightforward to do it yourself in the object itself, or a helper method tied to the model.

Comment: I want to copy those referenced entities. Though PostDetails will also get cloned first so I want to save a new id in there while cloning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a copy using constructor or the builder pattern, or to set the properties using simple setters. Then, persist the new entity instance using the EntityManager's `persist()` method. To avoid issues with duplicated `id` values, you must not copy the `id` field and instead let the `JPA` generate a new `id` when the entity is persisted.

Code example

```java
public class Post {

    // constructor, getters and setters are omitted

    public Post(Post post) {
        //Don’t copy id!
        this.title = post.getTitle();
        this.comments = new ArrayList<>(post.getComments());
        this.details = new PostDetails(post.getDetails());
    }
}

public class PostDetails {

    // constructor, getters and setters are omitted

    public PostDetails(PostDetails details) {
        // Don’t copy id!
        this.description = details.getDescription();
        // copy other fields as needed
    }
}

// Usage
public class PostsRepository{
    @Autowired
    EntityManager em;

    public void saveCopy(Post originalPost){
      Post clonedPost = new Post(originalPost);
      em.persist(clonedPost);
    } 
}
```

Also I would highly recommend you to write [tests](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test) in order to check that you are doing everything fine. Moreover you will more space for experiments.